# How to change the user iis 5 service runs on?

Tags: windows-service, iis

I have IIS 5 running over XP.
I was told to change it such that the iis process does not run under the system account.
Where do I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services

Just look for the name of the service you want to change, right-click it, and select properties. On the Log On tab set the username and password you want to use. It will require a restart of the service before it takes effect so watch out for that.

Possible IIS related services that may need to be changed:

- Iisadmin: IIS Admin Service
- Msftpsvc: FTP Publishing Service
- Nntpsvc:  Microsoft NNTP Service
- Smtpsvc:  MicrosoftSMTP Service
- W3svc:  World Wide Web Publishing Service

Comment: what is the process name for iis 5?