# "A required privilege is not held by the client."

Tags: windows-xp, windows-service, iis

I have iis5 on xp.
Everything was working until I had to change the user account of the iis windows service from Local System to another user ([details](https://serverfault.com/questions/192089/how-to-change-the-user-iis-5-service-runs-on)).

Now iis is up but when I surf it I get:

"A required privilege is not held by the client."

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you give more details?

My first instinct is to ask if the account that you're running IIS doesn't have rights to run as a service (but that doesn't quite match the error's wording.)

Just for sanity's sake, Have you granted the user "Run as a Service" privelige via the Local Security Policy?

[image: Local Security Policy MMC]

**UPDATE 1**: AH-HA!  (First, you did restart the IIS service after you made that change, right?  If it still doesn't work...) Remove the "Run as a Service" right and grant it the "Act as part of the operating system" right, and then restart the www service.  Also, for sanity's sake, clear your browser cache.  It shouldn't be a problem, but ...

**UPDATE 2**: Since you're running an ASP application (that's an important piece of information...), follow the steps described [here](http://support.persits.com/show.asp?code=PS01032619) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922737)

Also:

- [Instructions on how to create a
  service account for ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/dnpag2/html/paght000009.asp)
- [List of directories to which the
  ASP.NET service account needs
  permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/dnnetsec/html/secnetht01.asp)

Comment: it did not have this permission. but when I added it (And restarted the service) I got the same error.

Comment: @Yaron Naveh, changes to my answer; Check the Update

Comment: some progress! the iis runs and static html files are served. but when I try to access asp.net page I get the red "Server Application Unavailable"

Comment: aspnet_wp.exe could not be started. The error code for the failure is 80070522. This error can be caused when the worker process account has insufficient rights to read the .NET Framework files.

Comment: (this is from event log)

Comment: @Yaron Naveh Now we're cooking with Gas!  Read links and apply!

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure but same as gWaldo said it may be a setting in the Local Security Policy

i believe that you need to enable Impersonate a client after authentication (i may be wrong)

From [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;811320)

> To work around this problem, verify
>   that the ASPNET account has the
>   correct user rights as follows:
>
> %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\Version\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files: Full Control
>
> %windir%\Temp: Full Control
>
> Application folder: Read
>
> %installroot% hierarchy (for example,
>   %windir%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\Version):
>   Read
>
> %windir%\Assembly: Read
>
> Note This is the global assembly
>   cache. You cannot directly use Windows
>   Explorer to edit ACLs for this folder.
>   Instead, open a command window, and
>   then run the following command:
>
> cacls %windir%\assembly /e /t /p
>   domain\useraccount:R
>
> Alternatively, before you use Windows
>   Explorer, run the following command to
>   unregister Shfusion.dll: regsvr32–u
>   shfusion.dll
>
> After you set user rights in Windows
>   Explorer, run the following command to
>   re-register Shfusion.dll: regsvr32
>   shfusion.dll
>
> Web site root (for example,
>   %root%\Inetpub\Wwwroot) or the path
>   that the default Web site points to:
>   Read %windir%\System32: Read
>
> (Typically, the ASPNET account has
>   already been granted user rights as a
>   member of the Users group.)

Comment: where can I enable it?

Comment: It should be located in the same location as the Run as a Service option you tried earlier  -   "Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > Impersonate a client after authentication"

Comment: from the event log: aspnet_wp.exe could not be started. The error code for the failure is 80070522. This error can be caused when the worker process account has insufficient rights to read the .NET Framework files.

Comment: edited post with something i found on microsofts support site